# Testing a Field Sync utility without creating custom fields

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I've created a utility in Apex that syncs a Lookup(User) field on Account or Opportunity with a specified Account or Opportunity Team Member Role, based on a custom metadata configuration.

It's all working fine, but I'm not sure how best to write the test. Normally, when creating generic utilities, I try to rely on standard fields. However, as part of the functionality in this case requires that I be able to clear the field, I cannot use OwnerId, which is the only editable Lookup(User) field on Account/Opportunity.

So...is my only option to create a custom User lookup *only* for the purpose of testing? That feels bad, but I can't figure out another way...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the packaging model for this project? In 2GP, you can specify unpackagedMetadata so you can pass your tests, which would then allow your package to get installed anywhere.

Comment: @sfdcfox oh it’s not a package, I’m just developing it for my own org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use the [Unit Of Work pattern](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl/apex_patterns_sl_learn_uow_principles) plus [ApexMocks](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-mocks). I'll define the answer in terms of [fflib](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common) which has a Unit of Work implementation

Let's assume your utility is defined like this:

```
class MyUtility {
  void myMethod(Sobject sobj, SObjectField lookupField) {
    fflib_ISobjectUnitOfWork uow = Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance();
    ... figure out someNewVal
    sobj.put(lookupField,someNewVal);
    uow.registerDirty(sobj);
    uow.commitWork();
  }
}
```

Your test class then looks like:

```
// Given a mock environment
fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
// Given a mock Opportunity
Opportunity mockOppo = new Opportunity(...);

// Given other mock data required to make code under test execute
...

// Given a mock Unit of Work; injected
fflib_SobjectUnitOfWork mockUow = (fflib_SobjectUnitOfWork) mocks.mock(fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.class);
Application.UnitOfWork.setMock(mockUow);

// when myMethod
new MyUtility(mockOppo,Opportunity.OwnerId);

// then verify mockOppo sync'd as expected
((fflib_SobjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(mockUow,mocks.times(1)
                                .description('Oppo lookup field sb sync\'d')))
            .registerDirty( fflib_Match.sObjectWith(new Map<SObjectField,Object> {
                                Opportunity.OwnerId_=> theExpectedValue,
                                Opportunity.otherField => otherExpectedValue,
                                ...
             }));
```

So, what's happening here:

- UnitOfWork pattern intercepts all DML calls with methods - `registerNew` (insert), `registerDirty` (update), etc. The actual DML is deferred until `commitWork` is called.
- At testmethod time, you inject a *mock* `UnitOfWork` object so when the test runs, the real Unit Of Work object which actually does DML via its `commitWork()` method isn't actually called, only its mock implementation methods are called.
- Since the mocking framework (`ApexMocks` - built on top of `Test.StubAPI`) captures all the mocked object's method calls, you can verify that the code-under-test's `registerDirty` was called once and with the sobject value(s) you expect. You can also verify that `commitWork()` was called so you know DML actually will get executed with the unmocked UnitOfWork.
- This way, you can reuse `OwnerId` because at testmethod time, you aren't actually committing any DML.

Pretty powerful stuff here and I'll admit a bit of a learning curve but the UnitOfWork pattern is super useful when dealing with unit testing of DML on objects that are otherwise hard to setup in testmethods (or when you just want to isolate your unit tests without doing tons of DML setup)

I recommend reading Chapter 12 of [Lightning Enterprise Platform Architecture](https://www.packtpub.com/product/salesforce-lightning-platform-enterprise-architecture-third-edition/9781789956719) (plus the rest of the book is super useful too) to understand how ApexMocks and UnitOfWork pattern collaborate.

Comment: Thanks! I've actually taken a look at fflib in the past and its various uses, including UnitOfWork, but we never implemented it because it felt so heavy for our relatively small & simple org. But perhaps it's time to revisit. In the meantime though, we do actually use an intermediary class to handle DML, so I could mock that and achieve the same end result...or so I think, if I've understood your broader suggestion correctly.

Comment: even in small orgs fflib is worthwhile to enforce discipline; and in fact, the smaller the org, the easier to adopt. fflib UnitOfWork doesn't depend on selectors, domains, or services so you could adopt that first - but you are correct, abstracting away the DML into something mockable is the gist of my approach.

Comment: We actually use an adapted service/selector/domain pattern and it's been working great. Maybe this is the year we also add in UnitOfWork. In any case, I'll go ahead and try the mock suggestion this time around. Thanks again!